# Display response to a GET & POST request in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the response of a GET request inside a textfield on my webpage using jquery. Currently, I have the following code with which I can get the response on the console.

```
$(document).on('click', '#get-button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $("#url").val(),
        data: '',
        success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '#post-button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#url").val(),
        data: $("#json-data").serialize(),
        success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Below is a part of the HTML code where I want to fit the response(in JSON) format.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">JSON Response</div>
      <div class="panel-body text-danger">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="server response"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Place your code in ready function, or add deffer to your script definition. In that way your script will execute after DOM is loaded.
2. Don't add events on docuemnt like this, it is too big. You are using id's, thats nice, so use it:) It depends on your DOM size, butin most cases find a element by id and then add event to it.
3. Add an id to your textbox, that will be more usable and faster.

.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#get-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: $("#url").val(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('.form-control').val(response); // personally I would give your textbox an ID
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

  $('#post-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $("#url").val(),
      data: $("#json-data").serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('.form-control').val(response);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
})
```

If your URL are correct, this will work.

Just remember that after you get the response, and you will get a JSON object, you will have to convert it to String using JSON.stringify().

I will try to explain. In Javascript we have Objects and simple types (boolean, String, float, etc). When we want to print a simple type, we just see it's value. But when we want to display a Object, JS engine has a problem, because each object can be very big, complex. Thats why when printing an object or JSON (witch is an Object) we get [Object]. Luckilly JSON is so popular that JS has an default methods for serializing String to JSON (JSON.parse(someString)) and other way around (JSON.stringify(JSONObject)).

Comment: I tried above code, but it only displays [object Object] in the required textarea. Am I missing something?

Comment: It depends on returned content type, if it is a JSON than use JSON.stringify() to make it a string.

Comment: If I want to display it in JSON format like the Advanced REST Client does, do I have to use the JSON.stringify() ?